# DOM remove a checkbox javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, checked

I'm quite new to Javascript and don't know where to start for this one. I have a list of checkboxes. I want to achieve when a checkbox is checked, the checkbox is removed from the list. I found some different solutions but they all have a button you need to press to remove the checkbox and i just want the checkbox removed when it's checked.

This is how my HTML looks like:

```
<ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox"> Item 1
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox"> Item 2
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: $(this).remove??

Comment: 1. Find the type of element you are interested
$('thatelement')
2. Attach .change method to that
3. Write function that you are expecting to happen when you do change that element
(this).remove() or maybe (this).hide if you want just to hide it

Comment: Thanks for your help! i'll check this out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how precise you need to be, here is one that will remove the parent LI when clicked

You can add `if (this.checked) { ... }` if you only want to remove when checked

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click",function() {
    $(this).closest("li").remove(); // $(this).remove(); to remove the checkbox only
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox"> Item 1</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox"> Item 2</label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this code , this is removing current checkbox while you are clicking on checkbo

**Code Here**

```js
$( '.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]' ).change( function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```